# TS code scanning does not return error but tslint returns a list of errors

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

i am having a strange issue - for TS sources, the sonarQube runs but does not return errors. I am using the SonarTS plugin.
SonarQube returns 0% errors. Any idea what could be wrong. Thanks.

My sonar-project.properties has the following -

```
sonar.projectKey=CCW:20feb11
sonar.projectName=CCW20feb11
sonar.projectVersion=0.1
sonar.scm.disabled=true
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.ts.tslint.path=node_modules/tslint/bin/tslint
sonar.exclusions=/node_modules/
sonar.ts.tslint.configpath=tslint.json
sonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json
```

The logs of sonar-scanner -X are attached -
https://www.dropbox.com/s/uadxpz6nba866q3/CCW-logs.txt?dl=0

The tslint.json & tsconfig.json are also attached in the following zip file -
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zw2m2e5l40cih8i/jsonfiles.zip?dl=0

Update: I observed that the Tslint returns errors.

Thanks in advance.
Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checks done by tslint and SonarTS are not the same (although some rules are shared), so it is normal that issues raised can be different. I see from the logs that you are using minimal "Sonar Way" quality profile, you can set "Sonar Way Recommended" quality profile for the project in SonarQube if you want to enable more rules.